# Making a directory on a path stored inside a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm new in batch programming. The thing is I have a path and a new folder name in 2 variables, so I want to concatenate it and make a new folder in that result path. I tried many things but nothing worked. Please help

I tried this code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ver=project
set spath=d:\a\svn\
set path=!%spath%%ver%!
mkdir %path%
pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `path` as name for an environment variable because such an environment variable is defined already by default with a very important meaning, see the answers on [What is the reason for 'sort' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/)

To concatenate two environment variable values just reference those two environment variables on assigning the value to one of the two environment variables or a new environment variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ProjectVersion=project"
set "SvnPath=d:\a\svn\"
set "ProjectPath=%SvnPath%%ProjectVersion%"
mkdir "%ProjectPath%"
pause
endlocal
```

See also answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for the reason using `set "variable=value"` with double quotes around string value to variable assignment, i.e. around the argument string of command **SET**.

The commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** would not be really necessary here.

Possible would be also:

```
@echo off
set "ProjectVersion=project"
set "SvnPath=d:\a\svn\"
set "ProjectPath=%SvnPath%%ProjectVersion%"
mkdir "%ProjectPath%" 2>nul
if not exist "%ProjectPath%\" echo Failed to create directory "%ProjectPath%" & pause & goto :EOF
```

The batch file above creates the directory with suppressing any error message by redirecting **STDERR** to device **NUL**. An error message is output if the directory already exists or it was not possible to create the directory because NTFS permissions denies folder creation for current user or in directory path there is a file with the name of a directory in path, e.g. there is a file with name `project` in directory `d:\a\svn` or there is a file `svn` in directory `d:\a`. The next command with a backslash appended to directory path checks if the directory exists after execution of command **MKDIR** and outputs an error message with **PAUSE** and next exiting batch file when the directory still does not exist.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` and [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of `&` operator.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you. The modified code without setlocal done the trick .You're a life saver :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set version=project
set spath=d:\a\svn\
set mypath=%spath%%version%
mkdir %mypath%
pause
endlocal
```

`path` is a reserved name - it defines the sequence of directories that is searched for an executable if the executable is not found in the current directory. If you change it, well - in short, **gloom**

`ver` is not a reserved name, but it *is* the name of a inbuilt utility and makes a poor choice for variable-name.

Your code was attempting to set your desired new pathname to the *contents of* the variable `d:\a\svn\project`. Since this variable is very unlikely to exist, you would have attempted to make a directory named *nothing*.

btw - there is no need to set `mypath` - `md %spath%%ver%` would work just as well. `MD` is a synonym of `mkdir` and is used more often.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that.